# Kubernetes outbound request to use service IP

Tags: kubernetes

In our Kubernetes deployment, we have deployed a WebApp on a deployment controller and created a Load-balancer for external access.
So all the inbound request is getting load-balanced by load-balancer and works fine.

But we are facing issue with our outbound request.In our case external application can only accept traffic from whitelisted IP addresses so we wanted to give load-balancer ip which will then get whitelisted as pods are ephemeral in nature and their IP will not be static.

But as request are originating from pod, it keeps the source ip of pod and then external application drops the request.

Is there a way in which pod can send outbound request using source as service ip, or can source ip be masked by service Ip?

Comment: this will help apply network policy 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-policies

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially use a egress gateway for this. Istio provides Envoy as a egress gateway proxy. From your service inside the cluster all outbound traffic will be routed through this egress proxy. You can configure TLS origination at the proxy before the traffic is send to the external service. You need to then whitelist the IP of the egress gateway in your external service.

Other option will be to have a reverse proxy in front of that external service and terminate traffic from service inside kubernetes and start a new TCP session from the reverse proxy to the external service. In this case the reverse proxy accepts connection from any origin IP but the external service only receives request originated from the proxy. You can configure the proxy to pass the actual client IP in a http header typically X-Forwarded-Host

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Kubernetes in IPv4 mode. When you are accessing an external IP address from the kubernetes pod, the requests are source NAT'd. This would mean that the packet would have the IP address of the host's (VM?) ethernet interface through which the traffic flows out. Please whitelist this IP and see if that helps

This would be a good reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Omvgd7Hg1I

Please note that service IP is useful when other services want to discover and talk to other services and IP table (in  kube-proxy ip-table mode) translates it to POD IP. Its not in play for the traffic originating from the given service